# Extension manifest to set version as 3.4 or greater

Tags: joomla-3.x, custom-component

As per the [link here](https://docs.joomla.org/Manifest_files) the version can be either 2.5 or 3.0. But my requirement is to have the version anything greater that 3.4 in 3.x series.

How this can be done? Should I go via scrip file? Or is there a simple setup in xml file itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to use only 2.5 or 3.0, you can also use 3.4 or any other Joomla version:

```
<extension type="component" version="3.4" method="upgrade">
```

The version attribute specifies the minimum Joomla! version needed for your extension, ie your extension will work with 3.4 and every version after that.

Comment: I understand that I can give any particular version. In that case when joomla 3.5 or any newer version released then I need to edit the manifest file... Is that something I can set greater than or equal to 3.4?

Comment: If you write "3.4" this means >= 3.4. It is the minimum Joomla! version required for your extension

Comment: mmmmm I thought the extension will work only on that version.... OK good to know that it is the minimum version.